Steps to conduct a linear mixed model and post-hoc comparison test
I would like to ask for your help with the best way to analyze the following experiment within R.
Here is my design: there are 15 treatments, in four blocks. For each treatment, in each block, we have five plants, in which we evaluated six leaves for disease severity.
Initially, I used the linear mixed model considering plants and leaves as random effects, below is the function:
mix <- lmer(sev ~ Treat + Block + (1|Plant/Leaf),
        data = sev)

Is it correct? Should I consider Block as a random effect as well? Why?
However, it didn’t fulfill assumptions for ANOVA, so I transformed with log, squared root, and box-cox, without success yet.
Then, my second idea was to summarize the data by mean severity per plant and use plants as random effects. Here is the model (is it ok?):
mix2 <- lmer(sev_mean ~ Treat + Block + (1|Plant),
        data = sev_m)

However, I found normality and homogeneity of variance after using log+0.5 transformation:
mix3 <- lmer(log+0.5(sev_mean) ~ Treat + Block + (1|Plant),
        data = sev_m)

In sequence, I proceeded to the post hoc comparisons. I tried to use the Scott-Knott test*, so I took a look at Chat GPT and it was suggested to obtain a linear model with the fixed effects (in this case treatments, right?) and then run the analyses. Is this correct? Are there other ways to do these comparisons? Do you suggest a package to run this step?
*I tried Tukey's test also, but I have group superposition and couldn't easily identify the best treatments. 
Thanks for your help!

what "assumptions for ANOVA"did you check ? This model is not an ANOVA.

I mean that I tested for normality and homogeneity of variances.
Is it the best way? What should I do so?

The distribution of the variables is not relevant. It’s the distribution of the residuals that matters.
